# Date Format changed, but only in e-mail

Tags: sharepoint-online, outlook, power-automate

I have built a flow which collects data from a Form to Excel file, saves the each new form record as a new row in the file in SharePoint and summarizes the form data into an e-mail.

The form collects the dates from the form in MM/dd/yyyy format, and it populates the records into Excel in that format.  However, when I use the date fields to populate the e-mail, the e-mails send in yyyy/MM/dd format.  How can I get the e-mails into the format I want?

I can't figure out why the Form, and the Excel file are correct, but "Office 365 Outlook" seems to change the date format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Date time formatting is a constant problem I come across also!

Have you tried formatDateTime() expression to just "remind" it?

For example, if your dynamic content field for date is 'Timestamp' from your original trigger:

formatDateTime(triggerBody()?['Timestamp'],'MM/dd/yyyy')

Type **formatDateTime(** into Expression, then click over to Dynamic content tab and click the date field from your form, then type in **,'MM/dd/yyyy'** and press **OK**. Hope that works for you!

[image: formatDateTime snippet]

[image]

Comment: Yes, I have tried that with my fields ['Start Date'] and ['End Date'] Dynamic fields, and it kept returning to me with the entire text of the formula into the emails.  I tried adding this just above the Email action, and I tried it before those actions after the trigger and get responses action.  It didn't work for me, so I need specific instruction on what action to use and where to make this work.

Comment: You can put it directly in wherever you are already putting in the date. You don't need a totally separate action. You just need to make sure the formula is inputted as an expression. You can also make the formula up in a Compose action, but it's ultimately the same. You still have to put the formula in Expression.

Comment: The formula should come up as a pink box if you've done it correctly.

Comment: I typed it in exactly like this:   formatDateTime(triggerBody()?['Timestamp'],'MM/dd/yyyy')  with my field names instead of "Timestamp".  Do you use the single quotation mark to surround the field name and the date format?  ['Timestamp'] and 'MM/dd/yyyy'  or are those just placeholders in the examples and you don't actually write it in the formula?

Comment: Status
Test failed
Error
Flow Run Failure: One or more fields provided is of type 'Null'.
I tried it with 'Start Date' the name of my field and 'StartDate' with no space and I get the same Null error.

Comment: Rather than typing it in, try clicking across to the Dynamic Content tab and scrolling down to find your start date/end date and click on it to populate the formula. It may look more like (triggerBody()?[Get_form_response]?['Start Date']. The single quotations are needed.(Null means there isn't anything to process and it expects something, so either the formula is looking for the wrong thing or there was no date inputted in the form.)

Comment: When I roll over the dynamic content field, it shows:  body('Get_response_detail')?['really-long-string-of-letters-and-numbers'].   I know that there are dates put in the form because when I use my dynamic fields, they are returning in the email as yyyy/MM/dd.  And they are required fields in the form, you must use a date picker on the form to choose them, so they definitely are not blank fields.

Comment: Okay, here is another clue.  The Form date submission field says "Please input date in format M/d/yyyy" and has the calendar date picker embedded.  I don't see any way to change this in the form itself.  So this explains the null error.  So that is the reason it wasn't working.  However, it doesn't solve the problem unless there is a way to change this default format in the Form.

Comment: The really long string of numbers is the form's ID or answer ID. Try it with with that for sure! Trust that any dynamic fields (no matter how weird the string of letters and numbers is) is the correct code for that bit of information. See how you go!

Comment: 1. Click where you want the date to go on your email  2. Go to the Expression tab (next to dynamic field tab)  3. type in `formatDateTime(` - it will do the second closing bracket automatically.  4. click the dynamic content tab. The formula should still show on the text bar. Scroll down, find the date dynamic field that you want. Click on it so it shows in the formula.  5. Click on the Expression tab again. Type in the rest of the formula inside the original brackets. `, 'MM/dd/yyyy'` Use single quotes and capital MM.  6. CLICK OK. A pink rectangle will appear that looks like a dynamic field.

Comment: (and make the date questions in your form a required field)

Comment: Woohoo! Thank you so much, that worked!

Comment: HOORAY! So pleased you got it to work!

Answer (score 0):

Please use the formatDateTime() expression to format the date to MM/dd/yyyy.

Similar issue:

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/How-to-format-date-value-in-email-body-to-display-as-MM-dd-yyyy/m-p/193671

More information:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/system-center/orchestrator/standard-activities/format-date-time?view=sc-orch-2019

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#formatdatetime

Comment: I don't understand how to apply this example to my flow.  I have a "Start Date" and "End Date" that I want to convert.  These appear both in the Subject Line and the Body of the email.  In the Apply to Each section, I don't have "value" or "modified" to choose from under "dynamic" content.

Comment: If possible, please provide detailed steps in your flow so that I can test and update the results for you.

Comment: Thank you @Julie_MSFT  I'm not sure how to add a screenshot.

Form-When a new response is submitted
Get Response Detail - "list of responses"
Branch to
Email me with the details (Outlook)
and
Add a row in an Excel sheet.

The form generates and updates to the Excel sheet in MM/dd/yyyy
But the date fields in the Email convert to yyyy/MM/dd

Subject:  Vacation - "Your Name", "Start Date" to "End Date"
Body:  "Your Name has requested vacation
Dates"  "Start Date" to "End Date"